# How to retrieve particular part of string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have got a directory listing as a String and I want to retrieve a particular part of the string, the only thing is that as this is a directory it can change in length

I want to retrieve the file name from the string

```
"C:\projects\Compiler\Compiler\src\JUnit\ExampleTest.java"
"C:\projects\ExampleTest.java"
```

So in these two cases I want to retrieve just `ExampleTest` (the filename can also change so i need something like get the text before the first `.` and after the last `\`). Is there a way to do this using something like regex or something similar?

Comment: Wouldn't it be best for all involved if you showed the fruits of your efforts first and told us why it didn't work? So in that vein, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use Apache Commons [FileNameUtils](https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) rather than coding your own regular expressions ? From the doc:

> This class defines six components within a filename (example
>   C:\dev\project\file.txt):
>
> ```
> the prefix - C:\
> the path - dev\project\
> the full path - C:\dev\project\
> the name - file.txt
> the base name - file
> the extension - txt
> ```

You're a lot better off using this. It's geared directly towards filenames, dirs etc. and given that it's a commonly used, well-defined component, it'll have been tested extensively and edge cases ironed out etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
new File(thePath).getName()
```

or

```
int pos = thePath.lastIndexOf("\\");
return pos >= 0? thePath.substring(pos+1): thePath;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File("C:\\projects\\ExampleTest.java");
System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile().getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex in `c#` and it works in `java` **:P** too.Thanks to `Perl`.It matches in Group[1]

```
^.*\\(.*?)\..*?$
```

Comment: decided to use  FileNameUtils, but sheers for the answer... +1

Answer (score 1):

**Java code**

```
String test = "C:\\projects\\Compiler\\Compiler\\src\\JUnit\\ExampleTest.java";
String arr[] = test.split("\\Q"+"\\");
System.out.println(arr[arr.length-1].split("\\.")[0]);
```